# Javascript, tratando código unicode

Tags: javascript, html

Como posso imprimir o caractere de um código Unicode?

Por exemplo:

```
var i = "\u0062";
```

Como converto esse código para o caractere que ele representa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplesmente imprima-o:

```html
<script>
    var i = "\u0062";
    document.write(i); // imprime: b
</script>
```

> "*- Como converto esse código para o caractere que ele representa?*"

Essa "conversão" é feita automaticamente. É muito normal você ver códigos escritos assim após serem obfuscados. Já até foi feita uma [pergunta sobre obfuscação de códigos JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/251856/como-funciona-a-obfusca%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-em-javascript?rq=1) aqui.

---

Mas se, por algum bom motivo, você quiser converter "na mão", tem essa pequena função que pode te auxiliar:

```js
function unicodeToChar(text) {
   return text.replace(/\\u[\dA-F]{4}/gi,
          function (match) {
               return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(match.replace(/\\u/g, ''), 16));
          });
}

var i = "\u0062";

document.write(unicodeToChar(i));
```

> Fonte: resposta do [Bryan Rayner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1497100/bryan-rayner) no SOen: [Converting unicode character to string format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22021709/5988245) (Ctrl+C > Ctrl+V).
>
> Leitura recomendada: [MDN - String.fromCharCode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode);

---

Achei que seria interessante compartilhar, também, essa tabela que uso bastante nas minhas consultas: [RapidTable - Unicode characters table](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.html);

Comment: Como seria em string?

Comment: @LinhadeCódigo Abre essa documentação que postei o link. É só você passar os códigos numéricos de cada caractere separados por vírgula que o método retorna a string convertida. Use a função que postei como modelo. 